# aws sdk boto3 using describe_security_groups()

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, boto3

I have a script and I'm trying to fetch the `GroupName` under `UserIdGroupPairs` (for ingress and egress rules); however, when I do the following, I don't see `GroupName` at all under `UserIdGroupPairs`:

Below is the inbound rule of my security group (`sg-xxx123` with group name of `SG-Test`) from the console. Clearly, the inbound rule has security group id of `sg-xxx456` and a group name of `SG-ingress`

| Type | Protocol | Port range | Source | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HTTP | TCP | 80 | sg-xxx456 / SG-ingress | SG-Test-Description |

Here's my response:

```
sgs = ec2.describe_security_groups()["SecurityGroups"][0]
```

output:

```
{'Description': 'SG-Test', 'GroupName': 'SG-Test', 'IpPermissions': [{'FromPort': 80, 'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'IpRanges': [], 'Ipv6Ranges': [], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'ToPort': 80, 'UserIdGroupPairs': [{'GroupId': 'sg-xxx456', 'UserId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Description': 'SG-Test-Description']}], 'OwnerId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'GroupId': 'sg-xxx123', 'IpPermissionsEgress': [{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}], 'Tags': [{'Key': 'Environment', 'Value': 'sandbox'}, {'Key': 'Owner', 'Value': 'mgen'}], 'VpcId': 'vpc-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
```

Another response:

```
sgs = ec2.describe_security_groups()["SecurityGroups"][0]['IpPermissions'][0]['UserIdGroupPairs']
```

output:

```
[{'GroupId': 'sg-xxx456', 'UserId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'Description': 'SG-Test-Description'}]
```

According to boto3 document, it has `GroupName` under `UserIdGroupPairs`. See response syntax (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_groups)

Why am I not able to fetch `GroupName` under `UserIdGroupPairs` just like what it says in the boto3 document?

Answer (score 0):

`GroupName` is only used for default VPC and EC2-classic. For other VPC types must use `GroupId`. From [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_groups):

> he name of the security group. In a request, use this parameter for a security group in EC2-Classic or a default VPC only. For a security group in a nondefault VPC, **use the security group ID**.

In your case this will be:

```
'GroupId': 'sg-xxx456'
```